# Keyboard window snap-to-position on Linux

Tags: linux, gui

I'm looking for a Linux utility that allows me to define arbitrary keyboard shortcuts that will move the frontmost window to a specific absolute position on-screen, depending on the shortcut.

An OSX utility which does this is Breeze (http://autumnapps.com/breeze/ ) -- Is there a Linux equivalent?

Comment: Could you specify what window manager or desktop environment you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *wmctrl* to move a window, e.g.

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,100,50
```

to move to currently active window to position (100/50). See the man page for more about what the parameters mean.

Use your window manager or something like [LinEAK](http://lineak.sourceforge.net/) to bind this to keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)